# Como evitar que se duplica una lista al hacer onClick

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo unas lista en javascript pero cada vez que cambio de pestaña y regreso este concatena el contenido y me duplica el contenido. ...

**primera vez que me muestra el contenido**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**segunda vez que me muestra el contenido al darle click en el mismo apartado**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
function myfunction(params) {
    const data = {opc: 'getPedido'};
    fetchData(data)
        .then((val) =>{
            getTipoPedido(val)  
        }).then(()=>{
            let idPedido = document.getElementById('idPedido'+params).value;
            let data = {opc: 'getProductos', idPedido: idPedido};
            fetchData(data)
                .then((val)=>{
                     mostrarProductos(val,idPedido,params)
                })
        })
}
myfunction('Express')
```

```
function getTipoPedido(data){
  let express = data.filter(i => i.tipoEnvio == 1);
  let normal = data.filter(i => i.tipoEnvio == 2);
  let recoger = data.filter(i => i.tipoEnvio == 3);
  document.getElementById("expressLength").innerHTML = express.length;
  document.getElementById("normalLength").innerHTML = normal.length;
  document.getElementById("recogerLength").innerHTML = recoger.length;
  document.getElementById('idPedidoExpress').value = express[0].idPedido;
  document.getElementById('idPedidoNormal').value = normal[0].idPedido;
  document.getElementById('idPedidoRecoger').value = recoger[0].idPedido;
}
```

```
function mostrarProductos(data,idPedido,params) { 
    let list = '';
    data.forEach(i => {
        list +=
        `
        <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-action ">
            <div class="d-flex w-100">
                <h5 class="mb-1">${i.nombre}</h5>
            </div>
            <span>Cantiad: ${i.cantidad}</span>
        </div>
        `;
    });
    document.getElementById(params+'List').innerHTML += list;
    document.getElementById('idPedido'+params).value = idPedido;
}
```

Comment: Pon el html por favor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Antes de cargar la lista solo vacía el contenedor*

```
document.getElementById('id').innerHTML='';
```